# REST nested collection

Tags: rest

From the REST point of view what is a best way to work with resource's nested collection?
Let's consider Users and Articles. /api/users and /api/articles resources are accessible with PUT, POST, GET, DELETE methods, but what is the best way to show user's articles?

I see two ways:

1) user's structure have array with name articles, which keep all article ids for user. So, to  avoid multiple by-id requests /api/articles will support multiple id request in such form: GET /api/articles?ids=1,2,3,4,33

2) additional view methods with pagination support of such form: GET /api/users/:userId/articles

Each of them has pros and cons, but which of them is preferred and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot comment what the commonly preferred way is. I would argue that namespacing with the userId (2) looks nicer and is like the "web" is supposed to be.

Just by looking at this resource pattern makes sense to me and you can CRUD articles for this specific user.

Passing comma seperated articles IDs can get ugly when you have a user with 1.000.0000 articles and it looks like a function call with an array of parameters.

So I vote for 2).